# Scala - cycling over a finite sequence starting from a given element

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to efficiently cycle over a fixed sequence, starting from any one of its elements, not always from the beginning.
The solution I have been exploring is:

```
val directions = List("north", "east", "south", "west")
val cycle = Stream.continually(directions).flatten

cycle dropWhile (_ != "south") take 12 foreach println
```

Since I'm using this inside a hot loop, starting over and over again, and the actual sequence is pretty lengthy, I fear the `dropWhile` is going to cost me quite a bit.
Is there a way I can speed this up?
Am I ever doing it the right way?

**Edit**

Some good answers were given suggesting I should not use `Stream`s. The central question now becomes: how can I avoid using `dropWhile` or similar functions?

Comment: Is the list an input which is dynamically generated as your program runs or is it a fixed list? Can't you just reuse the same reference to the `Stream` once you've done the `dropWhile`? What's preventing that?

Comment: The list content is fixed at the start of the task. Basically I have to navigate through a list of possible relationships (for example `HunterHunted`) searching for the first element with a given property. Once found I reverse the relationship (`HuntedHunter`) and start from the next one... So I **can** reuse the same `Stream`, but I have to `dropWhile` again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example below indexes the values of the fixed sequence to avoid traversing the list each time a new stream is started.

```
package rando

object Faster extends App {
  val directions = Vector("north", "east", "south", "west")
  val index = directions.zipWithIndex.map { case (d, i) => d -> i }.toMap
  def streamWithStart(start: String): Stream[String] =
    directions.drop(index(start)).toStream.append(Stream.continually(directions).flatten)
  streamWithStart("east") take 10 reduce(_+" "+_) foreach print; println()
  streamWithStart("north") take 10 reduce(_+" "+_) foreach print; println()
  streamWithStart("west") take 10 reduce(_+" "+_) foreach print; println()
  streamWithStart("south") take 10 reduce(_+" "+_) foreach print; println()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implicit class that allows you to call a `.looped` method on any `Traversable`. I believe you'll find the `Iterator` it returns much more efficient than the result of flattening `Stream.continually`.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

/** Turns a Traversable into an infinite loop. */
implicit class TraversableLooper[A:ClassTag]( val items:Traversable[A] ) {
  def looped:Iterator[A] =
    if ( items.isEmpty )
      sys error "<empty>.looped"
    else
      new Iterator[A] {
      val array = items.toArray
      val numItems = array.length
      var i = -1
      def hasNext = true
      def next = {
        i += 1
        if ( i == numItems ) i = 0
        array(i)
      }
    }
}
```

Here it is in use:

```
scala> val directions = List("north", "east", "south", "west")
directions: List[String] = List(north, east, south, west)

scala> directions.looped dropWhile (_ != "south") take 12 foreach println
south
west
north
east
south
west
north
east
south
west
north
east
```

Also, do as much as possible *before* making the loop, e.g. the `dropWhile`:

```
( directions.looped dropWhile (_ != "south") take 4 ).toSeq.looped
```

Comment: This is nice, but it does not remove the need to call `dropWhile`

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, but the point of that last statement is *not* about eliminating the call to `dropWhile`. The point is to do the `dropWhile` *before* capturing the values for the `Iterator` (in the second call to `looped`) so that you don't have to run a filter on the `Iterator` to get the values you want. I don't know whether that's possible in your real code, of course, but it is possible for the example given; you create the list starting with the value you want, and you loop *that*.

Comment: Yes I understood... you can see my previous comment as a justification for not accepting the answer ;-)  This since in my code the creation of the iterator would go inside a loop, too

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Iterator` rather than `Stream`. `Stream` keep everything in memory, and become bigger and bigger.

```
scala> val directions = List("north", "east", "south", "west")
directions: List[String] = List(north, east, south, west)

scala> val cycle = Iterator.continually(directions).flatten
cycle: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> cycle dropWhile (_ != "south") take 2 foreach println
south
west

scala> cycle dropWhile (_ != "east") take 2 foreach println
east
south
```

Comment: Great advice, but see comment to AmigoNico's answer

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach, where `directions` key value `south` is shifted up to the head of the list, then we iterate for instance `4` times over the shifted list,

```
implicit class AddCycleToList[A](val list: List[A]) extends AnyVal {

  def cycle(times: Int, from: A): Unit = {
    val shiftBy = list span { _ != from }
    val shifted = shiftBy._2 ++ shiftBy._1
    for (i <- 1 to times) shifted foreach println
  }
}
```

Hence

```
scala> val directions = List("north", "east", "south", "west")
directions: List[String] = List(north, east, south, west)

scala> directions.cycle(4, "south")
south
west
north
east
south
west
north
east
south
west
north
east
south
west
north
east
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid recalculating as much as possible:

```
val cycle = Stream.continually(directions).flatten
val cachedStreams = collections.mutable.Map.empty[String, Stream[String]]

def cycleStartingWith(direction: String) = 
  cachedStreams.getOrElseUpdate(direction, cycle.dropWhile(_ != direction))
```

This won't work with `Iterator`s, however; in that case, I'd go with a variation on Dave Rando's answer.